# smart contract for automatic baking/endorsement rewards to delegators

Tags: baking, smart-contracts, rewards

It seems like a smart contract would be the most natural mechanism to use for implementing a automatic rewards payment system to a baker's delegators, and I'm curious if such a contract is possibly to write.

Is this possible?

Admittedly, I know close to nothing about writing actual smart contracts, thus the question.

(I'm also aware there are other solutions like Backerei and now TAPS to help with this, but these are off-chain).

Regarding a smart contract solution, one thing I'm definitely unsure about, is how would a baker be able to apply variable fees to delegators (maybe some delegators delegated to the baker during a cheaper promotion period, etc...), and how would a baker be able to dynamically update fee rates.

I recently read about a new upgrade that will be proposed to Tezos called [Burebrot](https://medium.com/cryptium/introducing-the-burebrot-protocol-upgrade-beebf202353a). Maybe it is not possible to automate rewards via smart contract until this or a similar proposal is integrated into the system?

Thoughts?

Comment: After more digging aroudn, I guess this article on bakerei pretty much confirms smart contracts can't do this yet: https://medium.com/cryptium/introducing-b%C3%A4ckerei-automated-rewards-payment-manager-for-tezos-bakers-written-in-haskell-ccead9599d3c

Comment: Thanks for citing TAPS. Give it a try ;) Being off-chain has the advantage that it does not need to run on a Tezos node. You may have a dedicated computer to make payments. TAPS has its own native wallet which you may fund with just enough to planned rewards distribution period.

Comment: @LuizMilfont Curious if you would still recommend TAPS? Edit: Ah, I see you are on of the creators! Cool, how happy are you with its progress? Looks like it is still being activity worked on. Any other payment distro options out there you admire?

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend taps, I have been running Tezos Japan for a year now and it has worked perfectly for me.  I can even pay out bond holders a set percentage we agree on.

Comment: I presume you mean this taps project https://github.com/TezosRio/taps? Curious if you would still recommend it?

Comment: TAPS is now in version 1.2.2 and is very stable. I don't have any complaint from bakers. It just works, paying delegators and bond poolers every cycle like a swiss clock. You can run TAPS outside a Tezos node, which is a huge advantage. I suggest you try it. You will love it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's impossible today either, give some thought out scheme (a smart contract is just some logic over a state) but it's not straight forward, no.

The "Burebrot" upgrade has an explicit goal of `Moving payments of rewards on-chain` so yes, that should help a great deal